# Rest EASY Path parameter

Tags: java, resteasy, regex-negation

I have to match a path where it does not contain a word so my path annotation looks like @Path("/{userId}/{managerId:?:CEO}") this means pass all the request to this method which does not match managerId to CEO (Reg Expr being ?:CEO. But since there is a ":" sigh in there the RestEASY framework does not like it. Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

In order to escape characters in the `@Path` annotation's value you need to add a `\` before the character you want to escape.

```
{managerId:?\:CEO}
```